# Multiple column names to quos in dplyr NSE

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I'm writing functions to automate a workflow for analyzing a lot of demographic data. I can get what I need from a regular pipe-stream of `dplyr` functions, but I need to abstract this into NSE functions. I'm supplying a column name to a series of `gather` calls via a `...` argument, but this only works with a single column; I need the option of using multiple columns. I'm having trouble with how to use `quos(...)` in this case.

There's more to the function, but I'm including just enough to show the error.

Sample of data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

race_pops <- structure(list(
    town = c("Hamden", "Hamden", "Hamden", "Hamden","New Haven", "New Haven", "New Haven", "New Haven", "West Haven","West Haven", "West Haven", "West Haven"), 
    race = c("Total","White", "Black", "Latino", "Total", "White", "Black", "Latino","Total", "White", "Black", "Latino"), 
    est = c(61476, 37043, 13209,6450, 130405, 40164, 42970, 37231, 54972, 28864, 10677, 10977), 
    moe = c(31, 1039, 998, 879, 60, 1395, 1383, 1688, 42, 1226,1119, 1032), 
    region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Inner Ring", "New Haven"), class = "factor")), 
    class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Here's a working bit that yields my desired output:

```r
race_pops %>%
    gather(key = measure, value = value, est, moe) %>%
    unite("grp2", race, measure, sep = "_") %>%
    spread(key = grp2, value = value) %>%
    gather(key = grp2, value = value, -town, -region, -starts_with("Total")) %>%
    head(10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    town       region     Total_est Total_moe grp2       value
#>    <chr>      <fct>          <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 Black_est  13209
#>  2 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 Black_est  42970
#>  3 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 Black_est  10677
#>  4 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 Black_moe    998
#>  5 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 Black_moe   1383
#>  6 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 Black_moe   1119
#>  7 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 Latino_est  6450
#>  8 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 Latino_est 37231
#>  9 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 Latino_est 10977
#> 10 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 Latino_moe   879
```

This is the function up to the point where I get the error:

```r
gather_grp <- function(df, grp = group, value = est, moe = moe, ...) {
    name_vars <- quos(...)
    grp_var <- enquo(grp)
    value_var <- enquo(value)
    moe_var <- enquo(moe)

    df %>%
        gather(key = measure, value = value, -(!!!name_vars), -(!!grp_var)) %>%
        unite("grp2", !!grp_var, measure, sep = "_") %>%
        spread(key = grp2, value = value) %>%
        gather(key = grp2, value = value, -(!!!name_vars), -starts_with("Total"))
}
```

The function works if I drop `region` and use just the single column `town`:

```r
race_pops %>%
    select(-region) %>%
    gather_grp(grp = race, value = est, moe = moe, town) %>%
    head(10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    town       Total_est Total_moe grp2       value
#>    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 Hamden         61476        31 Black_est  13209
#>  2 New Haven     130405        60 Black_est  42970
#>  3 West Haven     54972        42 Black_est  10677
#>  4 Hamden         61476        31 Black_moe    998
#>  5 New Haven     130405        60 Black_moe   1383
#>  6 West Haven     54972        42 Black_moe   1119
#>  7 Hamden         61476        31 Latino_est  6450
#>  8 New Haven     130405        60 Latino_est 37231
#>  9 West Haven     54972        42 Latino_est 10977
#> 10 Hamden         61476        31 Latino_moe   879
```

But I can't supply both `town` and `region` to the `...`:

```r
race_pops %>%
    gather_grp(grp = race, value = est, moe = moe, town, region)
#> Error in (~town): 2 arguments passed to '(' which requires 1
```

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can wrap with `c` and it should work

```
gather_grp <- function(df, grp = group, value = est, moe = moe, ...) {
    name_vars <- quos(...)
    grp_var <- enquo(grp)
    value_var <- enquo(value)
    moe_var <- enquo(moe)


    df %>%
        gather(key = measure, value = value, -c(!!!name_vars), -!!grp_var) %>%
        unite("grp2", !!grp_var, measure, sep = "_") %>%
        spread(key = grp2, value = value) %>%
        gather(key = grp2, value = value, -c(!!!name_vars), -starts_with("Total"))
}
```

-running the function

```
race_pops %>%
    gather_grp(grp = race, value = est, moe = moe, town, region)
# A tibble: 18 x 6
#   town       region     Total_est Total_moe grp2       value
#   <chr>      <fct>          <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 Black_est  13209
# 2 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 Black_est  42970
# 3 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 Black_est  10677
# 4 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 Black_moe    998
# 5 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 Black_moe   1383
# 6 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 Black_moe   1119
# 7 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 Latino_est  6450
# 8 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 Latino_est 37231
# 9 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 Latino_est 10977
#10 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 Latino_moe   879
#11 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 Latino_moe  1688
#12 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 Latino_moe  1032
#13 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 White_est  37043
#14 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 White_est  40164
#15 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 White_est  28864
#16 Hamden     Inner Ring     61476        31 White_moe   1039
#17 New Haven  New Haven     130405        60 White_moe   1395
#18 West Haven Inner Ring     54972        42 White_moe   1226
```

---

For the single column case, we need to `select` out the 'region' or 'town' as it will also be a column in the dataset (or that needs to be changed in the function)

```
race_pops %>% 
    dplyr::select(-region) %>% 
    gather_grp(grp = race, value = est, moe = moe, town)
```